# Get data from JSON file with PHP (empty result with numbers)

Tags: php, json

I'm trying to get data from the following JSON file using PHP

I Want To Get All URls (link) ,

```
http://www.google.com 
http://www.bing.com
```

**Json**

[image]

Here is what I tried

**PHP**

[image]

Thanks

Comment: Have you verified that `$obj` contains the data by using `var_dump` or similar?

Comment: works fine with `echo $obj->news->name;` MR @mulquin

Comment: I doubt that you can write `$obj->link->1->...` in PHP. Try `$obj->link[1]->url` instead.

Comment: @Hassan I tried But not working for me

Comment: Please dont post pictures of code, post the code as text. Also can you do an `print_r($obj);` and show us the result please. Add that to your question, dont post it as a comment

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot access an object property using a number, it must be a string.

It is much easier to output `json_decode` as an array, and access properties that way. To do this, put `true` as the second parameter.

```
<?php

$json = '
{
    "news": {
        "name": "yahoo",
        "url": "https://yahoo.com"
    },
    "links": [
        {
            "id": "1",
            "url": "https://google.com"
        },
        {
            "id": "2",
            "url": "https://bing.com"
        }
    ]
}';

$decode = json_decode($json, true);

echo $decode['links'][0]['url'];
```